# SQL AND Operator Not Working VERTICALLY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple MySQL table:

[image: look at the screenshot]

My SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT rpcf.place_id
FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
WHERE 
(
  (rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy') 
  AND 
  (rpcf.field_id = 22 AND rpcf.field_value = 'XL')
)
```

This query returns nothing, though `10035` place_id  item meets both conditions. Looks like the problem is that the data is in two different rows. How can I rewrite the query to get places_ids that have both 21/Italy and 22/XL?

Comment: `rpcf.field_id` can't have 2 values at the same time...You mean `OR`

Comment: SELECT rpcf.place_id FROM rel_place_custom_fields rpcf WHERE ((rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy')  OR (rpcf.field_id = 22 AND rpcf.field_value = 'XL')) maybe you need OR

Comment: Please read about formatting code in the edit help. What does "vertically" mean? Putting it in caps doesn't make it clearer. Also you are not clear about what you want. Please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: To make this clear: A `WHERE` clause looks at one record at a time. So you ask the DBMS to find a record where `field_id` is 21 and 22 at the same time, which is not possible of course - it can either be 21 or 22 or another value.

Comment: @B001 I definitely didn't mean OR. You are right, rpcf.field_id can't have 2 values at the same time. But I'd like to get those place_ids which have the filed_ids and field_values mentioned in my question even if they are in different rows.

Comment: So are you looking for places that have both 21/Italy and 22/XL or places that have at least one of the two?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner I'm looking for those that have both 21/Italy and 22/XL

Comment: See M Khalid Junaid's answer on how to do this. I'll post an alternative.

Comment: It's always a nuisance to work with key/value tables. Is there an urgent reason for you to use them? If you'd had a proper places table with country and size etc., you could simply `select * from places where country = 'Italy' and size = 'XL'`.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Unfortunately, yes, I have to use it. I understand that it can be not that convenient but is it OK from the point of view of efficiency and resources used?

Comment: It is more flexible. Users can add any attributes they want and apply them to a place. This comes at the cost of more complicated and slower queries. There should of course not exist fixed queries like `where field_id = 21 and field_value = 'Italy'` by the way. If the query writer knows that there is an attribute 21 that means country, then it makes no sense not to have a proper column for this. Queries would rather use variables or get written dynamically.

Comment: Another aspect is the lack of guaranteed data consistency. One place can have 21='Italy' and another 21='Itaaly'. A mere typo, but two different contents for the DBMS and the programs working with it.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Thank you. Yes, my queries are written dynamically.

Comment: And yet another point is obigatory and optional data. When you offer the users to add attributes, they should be able to say whether they are considered obligatory for a place. E.g. a place must always be in a country, but the size may remain unknown. The DBMS cannot help you here; you yourself must ensure that each place always gets an attribute 21, when attribute 21 is marked obligatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your query as below to get `place_id` who has all these attributes not only single attribute

```
SELECT 
  rpcf.place_id 
FROM
  rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
GROUP BY rpcf.place_id 
HAVING SUM(rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy') 
AND SUM(rpcf.field_id = 22 AND rpcf.field_value = 'XL')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Looks like that's exactly what I need.

Comment: @Игорь Зуев: Just for your information: this makes intense use of true = 1 and false = 0 in MySQL. `rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy'` evaluates to true or false, i.e. 1 or 0 and the sum will be 1 or 0, because there'll be one or zero records matching, and 1 or 0 means true or false again.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner By the way, taking into consideration your previous comment, I cannot use SUM if I want to use more than 2 conditions? Like `HAVING SUM(rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy') 
AND SUM(rpcf.field_id = 22 AND rpcf.field_value = 'XL') AND SUM(rpcf.field_id = 24 AND rpcf.field_value = 'SOME_VALUE')` won't work because it returns place_id when at least two conditions are met, not three. Any ideas about the way to overcome this?

Comment: @ИгорьЗуев It will work with 3 conditions or more unless each pair is unique in your filter clause and of course present in database

Comment: @Игорь Зуев: `SUM(rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy')` is short for `SUM(CASE WHEN rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) <> 0`. As M Khalid Junaid says: each condition is looked at separately.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with M Khalid Junaid's answer. The alternative would be to look up the conditions one by one:

```
select *
from places
where place_id in 
(
 select place_id from rel_place_custom_fields where field_id = 21 and field_value = 'Italy'
)
and place_id in 
(
 select place_id from rel_place_custom_fields where field_id = 22 and field_value = 'XL'
);
```

The same can be done with `EXISTS` clauses of course.

Comment: OR with JOINs also with different where filters

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid: Yes, but I don't like joins for filtering. Criteria belongs in the `WHERE` clause in my opinion. This makes the queries more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner What is the best way from the point of view of resources: using `EXISTS` clauses, `SUM` or to do it in the way you did it above?

Comment: `EXISTS` and `IN` should result in the same execution plan for the query, as they do the same. (Provided of course the DBMS's optimizer does a good job.). `IN` clauses are easier to read, so I prefer them over `EXISTS` clauses. (More complicated lookups, however, can only be written with `EXISTS`, then there is no choice.)

Comment: If you don't want any data from a place table (such as the place's name), aggregating `rel_place_custom_fields` should be fastest. This is why I suggested to go with M Khalid Junaid's answer. You can problably still speed that up by putting the criteria into a `WHERE` clause and simply count the matches: `SELECT place_id FROM rel_place_custom_fields WHERE (rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy') OR (rpcf.field_id = 22 AND rpcf.field_value = 'XL') GROUP BY place_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2`.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `OR` in between two different where conditions like this.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT rpcf.place_id
FROM 
    rel_place_custom_fields rpcf 
WHERE 
(
  (rpcf.field_id = 21 AND rpcf.field_value = 'Italy') 
  OR 
  (rpcf.field_id = 22 AND rpcf.field_value = 'XL')
)
```

also use `DISTINCT` to return uniq values of `rpcf.place_id`.

Comment: The answer is correct for "get places with Italy or XL", but the OP has now clarified that they are looking for "get places with Italy and XL" really.